# How do I configure a Jenkins multi-branch pipeline to build as a submodule?

Tags: jenkins, git-submodules

I have a project [kuma](https://github.com/mozilla/kuma) organized with submodules:

- [kuma](https://github.com/mozilla/kuma)

  - Jenkinsfile (configured to test kuma)
  - [locales](https://github.com/mozilla-l10n/mdn-l10n)
  - [kumascript](https://github.com/mdn/kumascript)

    - Jenkinsfile (configured to test kumascript)
  - A bunch of other files

I'd like to configure a multi-branch pipeline in Jenkins that watches for branches on the kumascript repo, to:

1. Check out the master branch of kuma
2. Update the locales to the commit in the master branch (a regular `git submodule update --init`)
3. Update the kumascript submodule to the branch to test
4. Run the Jenkinsfile in the kumascript branch

Is this possible? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me.

First, the `Jekinsfile` is read from the commit, before checkout, so it is easy to use the one in the `kumascript` submodule, and much, much harder (impossible?) to read it from a different repo.

In Jenkins 2.68 with Git plugin 3.4.1, I setup a multibranch pipeline. The one source is Git, pointing to the kumascript repository:

[image: Jenkins Git setup]

"Discover branches" finds branches in the repository and starts builds for them.

"Wipe out repository and force clone" works around an issue where `jgit` doesn't fetch a submodule repository before checking it out, and thus the target commit isn't available.  It causes an error that looks like this in the Jenkins logs:

```
> git fetch --no-tags --progress https://github.com/mdn/kumascript +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Checking out Revision 998d9e539127805742634ef1c850221cf04ca2c7 (build-with-locales-1340342)
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.MissingObjectException: Missing unknown 998d9e539127805742634ef1c850221cf04ca2c7
at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.WindowCursor.open(WindowCursor.java:158)
at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectReader.open(ObjectReader.java:227)
at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalk.parseAny(RevWalk.java:859)
at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalk.parseCommit(RevWalk.java:772)
```

This issue appears to be reported in https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45729, and is reported fixed in Git client plugin 2.5.0.

Wiping out the repo appears to force the full fetch, and may be necessary when installing in a parent project.

Jenkins is now configured to create a build for each branch in the repository. To check it out as a submodule, the parent project will need to be manually checked out in the Jenkinsfile. I used Jenkin's "Pipeline Syntax" tool to help construct the command

[image: Jenkins pipeline syntax tool]

After some formatting, this goes in my [Jenkinsfile](https://github.com/mdn/kumascript/blob/18b30f15e5c703fc77720cc18a7ddfca4bc9ebe1/Jenkinsfile):

```
    stage("Prepare") {
        // Checkout Kuma project's master branch
        checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
                  userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://github.com/mozilla/kuma']],
                  branches: [[name: 'refs/heads/master']],
                  extensions: [[$class: 'SubmoduleOption',
                                disableSubmodules: false,
                                parentCredentials: false,
                                recursiveSubmodules: true,
                                reference: '',
                                trackingSubmodules: false]],
                                doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                  submoduleCfg: []
                 ])

        // Checkout KumaScript in subfolder
        dir('kumascript') {
          checkout scm
        }
    }
```

This checks out the `kuma` project and its submodules, and then uses the "vanilla" checkout to checkout the requested branch, but in the submodule directory:

From then on, if I want to run a command in the `kuma` repo, I run it:

```
    stage('Build') {
      sh 'make build-kumascript VERSION=latest'
    }
```

and if I want to run it in the `kumascript` submodule, I wrap it in `dir`:

```
    stage('Lint') {
      dir('kumascript') {
        sh 'make lint VERSION=latest'
        sh 'make lint-macros VERSION=latest'
      }
    }
```